# Pandas read_html only returns headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, post, python-requests-html

The following code finds the table but only returns the headers, but when I open the url in the browser it shows many rows of data.

Furthermore, if someone knows how to interact with the dates parameter (see image) I would really appreciate :). I tried passing the parameters on the request but it's not working.

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/b3/indice/ifnc/historico/')
df[0]

# returns:
DATA    ABERTURA    FECHAMENTO  VARIAÇÃO    MÍNIMO  MÁXIMO  VOLUME



# I tried with requests, but also got and empty dataframe:

url = 'https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/b3/indice/ifnc/historico/'
params = dict(page=0, numberItems=99999, initialDate = '01/01/2022', finalDate = '31/12/2022', 
              symbol='IFNC')
r = requests.post(url=url,data=params)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)
df[0]
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1):

The table content is only visible once you load the page in a browser. You should use a webdriver with selenium. You can even find elements by id/xpath and interact with them (enter text, click...):

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/b3/indice/ifnc/historico/'

browser.get(url)

browser.find_element(By.ID, 'dateMin').send_keys("02/03/2022")
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'dateMax').send_keys("02/03/2023")

# wait until button is clickable
button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'see_all_quotes_history'))
    )
button.click()

# wait until all table rows are visible
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr/td[@class='sorting_1']"))
    )

df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, attrs = {'id': 'quotes_history'})[0]
```

Output:

```
            DATA ABERTURA  FECHAMENTO  VARIAÇÃO  MÍNIMO  MÁXIMO VOLUME
0    01/03/2023    9.824       9.687      -140   9.564   9.832    n/d
1    01/03/2023    9.824       9.687      -140   9.564   9.832    n/d
2    28/02/2023    9.821       9.824         4   9.779   9.952    n/d
3    28/02/2023    9.821       9.824         4   9.779   9.952    n/d
4    27/02/2023    9.882       9.821       -62   9.792   9.927    n/d
..          ...      ...         ...       ...     ...     ...    ...
296  08/03/2022   10.045      10.037        -8   9.954  10.225    n/d
297  07/03/2022   10.390      10.045      -332  10.001  10.391    n/d
298  04/03/2022   10.624      10.390      -219  10.283  10.624    n/d
299  03/03/2022   10.515      10.623       103  10.475  10.748    n/d
300  02/03/2022   10.640      10.515      -118  10.447  10.703    n/d

[301 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used the right url when you tried with requests ?

Following that same path, checking the Network tab from the browser inspector led me to the following API endpoint, surprisingly different than yours whereas it should be exactly the URL indicated in the **history** request from your screenshot ?

```
import requests

payload = {'page':0, 'numberItems':50, 'symbol':'IFNC'}
r = requests.post('https://www.infomoney.com.br/wp-json/infomoney/v1/quotes/history', json=payload)
r.status_code
```

Output: `200`

```
r.json()
```

Output:

```
[[{'display': '01/03/2023', 'timestamp': '1677628800'},
  '9.824',
  '9.687',
  '-1,40',
  '9.564',
  '9.832',
  'n/d'],
...
 [{'display': '19/12/2022', 'timestamp': '1671408000'},
  '9.341',
  '9.686',
  '3,69',
  '9.341',
  '9.737',
  'n/d']]
```

You can then surely work from that with [pandas.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to create your DataFrame.

Playing with the dates is then as simple as adding those fields to the payload, e.g.:

```
from datetime import date

format = '%d/%m/%Y'
payload = {'page':0, 'numberItems':50, 'initialDate': date(2023, 1, 1).strftime(format), 'finalDate': date(2023, 1, 8).strftime(format), 'symbol':'IFNC'}
```

EDIT: It turns out *json_normalize* is probably not the way to go as the json does not follow a `{key:value}` scheme. I went that way:

```
import pandas as pd
    
res = [[a['display'], b, c, d, e, f, g] for a, b, c, d, e, f, g in r.json()]
df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['DATA', 'ABERTURA', 'FECHAMENTO', 'VARIAÇÃO', 'MÍNIMO', 'MÁXIMO', 'VOLUME'])
```

Output:

```
         DATA ABERTURA FECHAMENTO VARIAÇÃO MÍNIMO  MÁXIMO VOLUME
0  06/01/2023    9.957     10.155     1,99  9.956  10.160    n/d
1  05/01/2023    9.665      9.957     3,03  9.665   9.980    n/d
2  04/01/2023    9.594      9.664     0,73  9.571   9.776    n/d
3  03/01/2023    9.902      9.593    -3,11  9.533   9.928    n/d
4  02/01/2023   10.253      9.902    -3,43  9.835  10.253    n/d
```